# Select the right side of the body on canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Hi i'm trying to select a very specific part on the body of a canvas to spawn an element in that range. Let me explain better:

I divided the canvas (so the body) in 2 part and on the left I put an element:

```
this.x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((this.width / 2) - 50) + 50);
```

where `this.width` is the whole screen's length. (i also made a limit of 50px to avoid the screens borders).

So the first element spawn to the left side of the canvas, and i need to do the same with the second element (x2) but to the right side of the screen.

and i'm not able to find a solution.

I left a part of my code down here, any ideas?

```js
class Mapping {
  constructor() {
    this.colors = ["purple", "red", "yellow", "green"];
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  start() {
    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;
  }

  generation() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, (this.height - 50), this.width, 50); //floor
  }
}

class Tank1 extends Mapping {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((this.width / 2) - 50) + 50);
    this.y = 100;
  }
  colorPlayer1() {
    return this.colors[0];
  }

  tank() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colorPlayer1();
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.x1, this.y, 45, 35);
  }
}

class Tank2 extends Mapping {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x2 = 500;
//i would like to put this element on the left side with the same rules of the first element
    this.y = 100;
  }

  colorPlayer2() {
    return this.colors[1];
  }

  tank() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colorPlayer2();
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.x2, this.y, 45, 35);
  }
}

let map = new Mapping();
let player1 = new Tank1();
let player2 = new Tank2();

map.start();
map.generation()

player1.tank();
player2.tank();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#game {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Use the same formula but add canvas.width so that becomes the minimum it will spawn. `Math.floor(this.width/2 + Math.random() * (this.width / 2) - 50);`

Comment: Also with classes you don't need to create one for each tank unless there will be some major fundamental differences. You can have one tank class and then pass the differences through the constructor arguments. here's a codepen https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/rNyYxPp